# Check and report Perl module missing

Tags: perl, perl-module

Is there any way to report the missing modules used in the Perl file beforehand instead of getting as an error.

I have something like `use Digest::MD5`, `use File::DosGlob` modules in my Perl program. Whenever the users run the script they are getting an error if there is no specific module installed in their system. They could not understand the default error message given by `@INC`. So I would like to clearly tell them that these modules need to be installed to run the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could build your own verification by using [a `BEGIN` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END). Those are run at compile time, just like [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) is. Keep in mind that `use Foo` is essentially nothing else as this:

```
BEGIN {
    require Foo;
    Foo->import;
}
```

The following code will replace all `use` statements with a single `BEGIN` and place them inside an [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html). That's essentially like a [try/catch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) mechanism.

We need the string `eval` (which is considered evil around here) because `require` only converts from package names with colons `::` to paths if the argument is [a *bareword*](http://perlmaven.com/barewords-in-perl). But because we have the name in `$module`, it's a string, so we need to place it into an `eval` according to [`require`'s docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

If that string `eval` fails, we `die`. That's caught by the outer `eval` block and [`$@`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) is set. We can then check if it contains our module name, in which case we naively assume the failure was because that module is not installed. This check could be a bit more elaborate.

We keep track of any failures in `$fails`, and if there were any, we stop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# all our use statements go here
BEGIN {
    my $fails;
    foreach my $module ( qw/Digest::MD5 File::DosGlob ASDF/ ) {
        eval {
            eval "require $module" or die; # because $module is not a bareword
            $module->import;
        };
        if ($@ && $@ =~ /$module/) {
            warn "You need to install the $module module";
            $fails++;
        }
    }
    exit if $fails;
}

# ...
```

Above I included `ASDF`, which I don't have, so when run it will say

> You need to install the ASDF module at /home/code/scratch.pl line 1335.

You might want to make that message a bit more verbose. If your users are not able to understand the default error message that Perl gives when it cannot find a module, it might be wise to include a guide on how to install stuff right there.

Note that both modules you listed have been included with Perl for [a while](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html) (read: since March 2002). So why would you want to do this for those modules?

```
$ corelist Digest::MD5

Data for 2014-09-14
Digest::MD5 was first released with perl v5.7.3

$ corelist File::DosGlob

Data for 2014-09-14
File::DosGlob was first released with perl 5.00405
```

---

A better way would be ship your program as a distribution that can be installed, and include a Makefile or a [cpanfile](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Module-CPANfile/lib/cpanfile.pod) or something similar that lists dependencies. There is a guide in [perlnewmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnewmod.html) on how to start a new module. You'd not want to upload to CPAN obviously, but the basics are the same.

With this, your users would get all dependencies installed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning _perlnewmod_. I always wondered how CPAN gets populated.

Comment: There is a lot more than just that doc @PerlDuck. There are various tools to start new distributions, and also a couple of guides. Maybe this is a good time to release something on CPAN. Go make a PAUSE account get started. :)

Comment: I really not familiar with makefile or cpanfile, the Begin is working for a single file Thank you for that, but if I want check for all the perl files in the folder how that could be done

Comment: @Senthil not with this approach. You will need something to know all the dependencies, and something else to check them. It's time to get familia with those concepts I believe.

Comment: Thank you Simbabque, let me go through and get familiar with those concepts work, so this can be achieved by those concepts right?

Comment: I guess it depends on your actual setup. You didn't say a lot about what those scripts do, how you ship them and who the users are.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Devel::Modlist](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Modlist), it will list all the required module for your program.

```
perl -d:Modlist test.pl
```

There's another module [Module::ScanDeps](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::ScanDeps) which comes with a utility `scandeps.pl` which you can use on your script as:

```
scandeps.pl test.pl
```

Note that [sanity checking your Perl code using `perl -c` is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908416/how-to-check-if-a-perl-script-doesnt-have-any-compilation-errors), so use it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really clear about what "beforehand" means.  To check if a Perl program's syntax is correct and directly included modules are resolvable, use

```
perl -c <perl-program.pl>
```

This checks the syntax of your file and ensures that any modules `use`d by your code exist.  However, it does not transitively check the entire dependency tree, only those mentioned in `perl-program.pl`.

Comment: If you mean modules `use`d in modules your code uses then yes, it does. What it can't do is check modules that are meant to be loaded at runtime using `require`.

Comment: If `test1.pl` uses `test2.pm` in the same directory, and `test2.pm` has a bad `use` statement it will be caught only with an expicit `perl -c test2.pm`, not `perl -c test1.pl`

Comment: Works for me with perl 5.24 and I'm quite sure it has always been like that.
`$ echo "use X;" >x.pl; echo "package X; use Y;" >X.pm; perl -c x.pl` results in `Can't locate Y.pm in @INC`

Comment: I have something like use Digest::MD5, use File::DosGlob; modules in my Perl program. whenever the users run the script they are getting an error if there is no specific module installed in their system. They could not understand the default error message given by @INC. So I would like to clearly tell them that these modules need to be installed to run the script.

Comment: The point here is that `-c` only does the _compile_ time. That's why it's _c_. During compile time, only `BEGIN` blocks (and thus `use` statements) are run, but not `require`s. Even if there are `use` statements inside a file that's being `require`d, those will not be seen at the initial compile time. Perl would switch back to compile time when it encounters a `require` during run time to compile the `require`d file.