# Prevent compiler execution of BEGIN / UNITCHECK / CHECK / INIT blocks

Tags: perl, perl-critic

I want to detect grammar errors in my perl code. I've found that `perlcritic` misses many of them, (eg a random `else` inserted before any `if`, so trying to compile with `perl -cw` looks like the only viable option.

However, I don't want to open myself up for executing code when checking for errors.

[This perlmonks post](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=853778)  shows that  in `BEGIN`, `INIT`, `UNITCHECK`, and
`CHECK` blocks can / do get executed when compiling.

Can I grammar check `perl` code without running any of it?

What about removing or renaming the block which could cause execution?

Comment: perlcritic and perl-tidy don't run the code,

Comment: @choroba I tried linting with `perlcritic` and all seemed well... until I tried compiling the code and got a whole bunch more errors.

Answer (score 2):

Neither [`perlcritic`](https://metacpan.org/release/Perl-Critic) nor [`perltidy`](https://metacpan.org/release/Perl-Tidy) execute any of the code they analyse/manipulate.

---

To properly parse Perl code, part of it needs to be executed.

For example,

```perl
BEGIN {
   if (rand() < 0.5) {
      *f = sub { 5 };
   } else {
      *f = sub() { 5 };
   }
}

print f + 2;
```

randomly outputs `5` or `7` because the last statement is randomly compiled as one of the following:

```perl
print( f( +2 ) );   # rand() >= 0.5
```

```perl
print( f() + 2 );   # rand() < 0.5
```

Ok, so that's pretty far-fetched. Or is it? How is that different than

```perl
use Module qw( f );   # No different than a BEGIN block.

print f + 2;
```

Ok, so prototypes are discouraged. But what about

```perl
say "foo";   # This is a sub call.

use feature qw( say );

say "foo";   # This isn't a sub call; this is the say operator.
```

This means that correctly parsing code that uses the `say` operator (not counting `CORE::say`) requires executing code. A lot code uses the `say` operator.

But, if you account for a few common special cases, and if you accept a certain amount of imprecision (like whether `say` is a sub call or the `say` operator), one could parse Perl code fairly accurately without executing any of it. This is the idea behind [PPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI).

- [`perlcritic`](https://metacpan.org/release/Perl-Critic) uses PPI. It doesn't execute any of the code it analyses.
- [`perltidy`](https://metacpan.org/release/Perl-Tidy) uses its own parser. It doesn't execute any of the code it analyses.
- [`perl -c`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) will execute `BEGIN` blocks (including `use` statements) and the like.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent explanation.  What about grammar errors?  Surely they can be detected without execution?  I'm currently using both `perlcritic` and (grudgingly) `perl -cw` in my `vim` linters, as the latter seems to be required for grammar errors.

Comment: You mean syntax errors? No. I used an example the produced two different syntaxes based on a random number. I could easily have made them incompatible syntaxes (e.g. by using `(&)` instead of `()`).